# Facebook SDK [FBAppEvents activateApp] crash randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, crash

I use Facebook SDK v3.14. And I found the method `[FBAppEvents activateApp]` crash randomly. Because the `[FBAppEvents activateApp]` should write in the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Our applicationDidBecomeActive should be call about 100M per day , about 10 days the  `[FBAppEvents activateApp]` crash about 1K times.

The crash log is here , any one help me , thx.

```
type: signal
subtype: SIGSEGV
shavalue: 1ebce91b2b00be8084bb4cae3b666f4c
content:
    •   Crashed thread 0x00000000
    •   0 Weibo 0x00718df5 -[WBRecordCrashLog p_updateBacktraceToDictionary:fromSigalCode:] + 408
    •   1 Weibo 0x00718757 signalHandler + 298
    •   2 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x38317f8b _sigtramp + 34
    •   3 CoreFoundation 0x2d4e1105 + 76
    •   4 UIKit 0x3016d039 + 236
    •   5 Weibo 0x00a0d349 +[FBUtility attributionID] + 44
    •   6 Weibo 0x00a282e5 +[FBSettings publishInstall:withHandler:isAutoPublish:] + 456
    •   7 Weibo 0x00a28119 +[FBSettings publishInstall:withHandler:] + 44
    •   8 Weibo 0x00a3949f +[FBAppEvents activateApp] + 34
    •   9 Weibo 0x0014b60d -[TweetterAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 40
    •   10 UIKit 0x2fe3f6bb + 374
    •   11 UIKit 0x2fe2a6e1 + 1088
    •   12 UIKit 0x2fdc66e9 + 3540
    •   13 UIKit 0x2fdc5851 + 72
    •   14 UIKit 0x2fe29ca9 + 616
    •   15 GraphicsServices 0x323fbaed + 608
    •   16 GraphicsServices 0x323fb6d7 + 34
    •   17 CoreFoundation 0x2d56ea67 + 34
    •   18 CoreFoundation 0x2d56ea03 + 346
    •   19 CoreFoundation 0x2d56d1d7 + 1398
    •   20 CoreFoundation 0x2d4d7ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    •   21 CoreFoundation 0x2d4d7ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    •   22 UIKit 0x2fe28ed1 + 760
    •   23 UIKit 0x2fe2414d UIApplicationMain + 1136
    •   24 Weibo 0x001723db main + 58
    •   25 Weibo 0x00147c04 start + 40
```

And I have download the Facebook SDK source code , the `[FBUtility attributionID]` is here:

```
+ (NSString *)attributionID {
    return [[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"fb_app_attribution" create:NO] string];
}
```

And I have find some doc , there's no doc tell me `pasteboardWithName` or `[UIPasteboard string]` will cause crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defenced the crash use Method Swizzling to exchange the method (`+[FBUtility attributionID]`) with my custom method

The code like this:

in `Appdelegate.m`

```
Method leftMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSClassFromString(@"FBUtility"), NSSelectorFromString(@"attributionID"));
Method rightMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSClassFromString(@"MyHackFBUtility"), NSSelectorFromString(@"attributionID"));
method_exchangeImplementations(leftMethod, rightMethod);
```

in `MyHackFBUtility.m`

```
+ (NSString *)attributionID {

    return nil;
}
```

And it runs well for a few months